# How to draw a graph with specific requirement?

Tags: matlab

Recently, I read a paper by

> Xiao, Lin, Stephen Boyd, and Sanjay Lall. "A scheme for robust
>   distributed sensor fusion based on average consensus." Information
>   Processing in Sensor Networks, 2005. IPSN 2005. Fourth International
>   Symposium on. IEEE, 2005.

where there is a graph I am very interesting, that is

[image]

As stated in the paper,

> This graph is generated as follows: we first randomly generate n = 50
>   sensor nodes, uniformly distributed on the unit square [0, 1] × [0,
>   1]; then connect two nodes by an edge if their distance is less than
>   1/4. In the particular setup of Figure 1, there are 200 edges.

My question is how to draw a graph like this by using `Matlab`?

Comment: You may get a better response by following the posting guidelines and showing us a sample data set **plus** what you've tried so far.

Answer (score 0):

I would advice you to use the following function:

http://fr.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/16131-plot-a-directed-graph

I have used it before and it worked perfectly for me. 

 I hope this helps!

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion, it helps, but not an idea one.